# How to show Laravel foreach loop fixed value?

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have already created the table view code but I want to show in foreach loop the fixed value for example if the post is "1" in dababase row it will show active and otherwise inactive.

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
           <th>Patient Name</th>
           <th>Date of Birth</th>
           <th>Gender</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Address</th>
           <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach($posts as $post)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ $post->patient_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->dob }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->gender }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->phone }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->email }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->address }}</td>
           <td>{{ $post->status }}</td>
       </tr>
       @endforeach
   </tbody>                        
</table>
```

Comment: Anything within `{{ }}` is normal PHP code so you can use a ternary (e.g. `$post->something === 1 ? 'active' : 'inactive'`

Answer (score 1):

You may construct if statements using the `@if`, `@else`, directives, instead of `{{ $post->status }}` :

```
@if($post->status == '1')         
  Active    
@else
  Inactive  
@endif
```

You can also use the ternary operator (`?`) is a shorthand for the `if`  `else` structure. Like this :

```
{{ $post->status == '1' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}
```